# Possibility to order favourites by "most recently changed"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, bookmarks

Until April 2009 "most recently changed" was the default (and only) way [favourites](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56285?tab=favorites#sort-top) were ordered; then it was changed so that you can sort them by views/newest/votes.

I have some 170 questions favourited, many of which are very [popular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read) [ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion) that keep popping up every once in a while. Now it's impossible to easily see which questions have new answers (or edits); you'd have to manually scan the dates in the favourite list to do that.

I consider favourites a list of stuff I've marked as *interesting*, something I'm *tracking*, and I'd think I wasn't alone with the habit of browsing SO by checking which of those questions have new answers.

So I propose that "recently-changed" ordering is re-added, along with the current options. What do you think?

---

**Edit**: as [indicated here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3369/order-favorites-by-the-date-they-were-marked-as-favorite/4203#4203), this feature has been implemented: there's now "recent" among the sort options on the favourites page. :-) As a bonus, user's own questions and answers can also be sorted this way. Thanks to everyone involved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd definitely like this. I loved the previous ordering.

The new ordering (date posted) is particularly confusing because there's nothing in the displayed data to show that it *is* by posted date: the date displayed is the most recent change date.

It also doesn't help that the tab tooltip still says "sort by most recent activity".

Answer (score 2):

I'd kind of like to see this for everything to be honest. For example: "You've earned badge foo!" is nice, but if I can't work out *how* I earned that, not so useful.