# Show updates to favorite questions in recent activity

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, recent-activity, bookmarks

I'd like updates to favorite questions to show in the recent activity page, just like updates to my own questions are shown.  As it stands now, favorites are little more than bookmarks, that require manual polling to check for updates.

Comment: +1. I think this is a great idea.

Comment: Assuming by "updates" you mean new answers etc., this is similar to my request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/995/possibility-to-order-favourites-by-most-recently-changed (At least the same goal would be achieved: no manual polling/scanning needed)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. your favorites view now has a "recent" sort (versus the "newest" sort which is based on CreationDate).
2. if you favorite a question, you opt in to updates on that question and they will show in your `/recent/` and light up the envelope, just as if you own the question.

Comment: Is it possible to add a new page (like each users "recent activity" on their own questions / answers) for the favourites, so that we can see what the changes are to each question (new answers, edits, etc.) rather than still having to manually poll the question to discover the changes?

Comment: Is it possible to get the recent Favorites list in RSS Feed form?

Comment: Wow!, favorites tab in recent page looks nice! Thanks

Comment: love the feature. wtg guys

Comment: I'm not sure if I really need to be notified every time someone edits some answer in the formatting sandbox. But probably I'm just using favorites in the wrong way... :)