# Scroll to new / show new when clicking on favorite

Tags: support, bookmarks

I have several [favorites with many posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature).

Sometimes I get a notification that something is new @ my [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/508666/peehaa?tab=favorites).

However when I click on it it just shows the page of the question and not the thing that is new.

This way it is hard to see what was new.

Is there a way to see what was changed / added (the reason I got notified) when I click on it from my profile page?

If there isn't a way to see it I will change from support tag to feature-request.

Comment: I thought a found it. But that's not it :( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52697/you-have-1-favorite-change-see-your-favorites-wtf

Comment: I don't know if you know about this, but when viewing a question, on the right side of the page, under the tags, it will have "asked", "viewed", and (if there are any answers) "active". If you click on the value for "active" (if present), it should take you to the most recent answer to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like on the home page and many other places: click the "5 minutes ago" or "2 days ago" in that list, and it will take you to the *very* last change.

[image]

There might have been multiple changes though. Sort the answers on Active to see those in order:

[image]