# Notify me of updates on questions I put a bounty on

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, notifications

So far, from what I have seen, I don't get notified of new answers on a question on which I put a bounty. Normal in the existing system, because this is not my question, so the only way for now is [to add it to favorites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3155/show-updates-to-favorite-questions-in-recent-activity/3808#3808).

However, since putting a bounty is like taking a bit control over the question (you are the one who wants an answer, most likely, and the one who will award the bounty), I think it would be nice if **these questions were notifying you, bounty placer, like they are notifying the person who asked the question.**

This notifications should be only while the bounty is active. If one wants to have more updates later, there is always the "favorite" possibility.

Comment: Do I get notified of new answers on a question when I add it to my favorites? Maybe not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out we notify you of new answers to a bounty you have an answer on for the past 7 months, [Kevin Montrose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose) put this in...we just didn't come across this meta request for it.

Tagging this with a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Answer (score 4):

I think it actually serves you better to mark the question as a favorite when you post a bounty on it. Remember that the activity envelope effects from favorites are the secondary feature - the original benefit was quick access to the question.

In the old system, you could always find your bounty questions because it's just in your questions asked (and since it lasts no more than 7 days and is a bounty, it should be within the first 2 pages of "Recent" sort). In the new system, I don't know how people plan to track their bounty questions. Maybe on Meta you can just find it on the Featured tab, but in the main sites it's definitely going to get lost in the mess of bounty questions.

This is useful because even if bounty questions reported activity in the same vein that favorited questions did, you won't get strict alerts when comments are posted on answers. And those are what you, as the bounty assigner, are probably going to be paying 50% of your attention to (the other 50% being the answers and their edits resultant from those comments). Since you won't get reports on all of that kind of activity, you need to have quick access to the question. And rather than split off some additional section of your profile for something that can only ever have a single item (because you can only assign 1 bounty at a time), it fits very nicely on your favorites.

---

A sidenote. The methods used for tracking activity from favorites has some implications if it is directly adopted for bounties. Namely, activating/deactivating the star will add or remove ALL history of activity to your envelope's records. So if implemented identically, then once the bounty ends, all of your former records would be removed entirely. Likewise you'd have all the answers and changes from before you assigned the bounty, but that has a much less significant effect. Perhaps this is your desired behavior, though, but I figured it'd be a good thing to point out.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you simply favorite the question after placing the bounty?

(since favorites now trigger new answer and edit notifications..)

Comment: Yes, I mentioned adding to favorites. But it's not really going into the "process" of the whole "putting a bounty" thing. Like I said, putting a bounty is putting you in the place of the question asker (moreover that most bounties like this will be made by users with enough reputation to edit, as well.)

Comment: One could, but that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @ether the only sensible implementation is to force it to happen, most likely -- when bounty starts, force the favorite on and disallow it from being unfavorited. When bounty ends, de-favorite.

Comment: I don't know if I'd treat it as a favourite.. the only advantage is the user can manually say "nope, I don't want to watch activity on this question after all" and defavourite it. Otherwise, the system should simply provide activity updates on it without treating it *as* a favourite. (i.e. classification "favourite" and classification "bounty" have the same behaviour in this case, but that doesn't mean that it actually marked as a favourite in the DB (where it would inherit all other behaviours of a favourite).

Comment: I was just about to post the exact same feature request :) adding a favorite is not really a solution here.

Comment: @Jeff But if a user placing the bounty had already marked the question as a favorite, de-favoriting it automatically would be the wrong action to take.

Answer (score -1):

The easy fix is for the system to mark any question as one of your favorites when you put a bounty on the question.

Someone can always just take it of the favorites list, if they don't want to be informed of changes.