# Minor spelling mistake on the authorized applications page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, spelling, se-applications

The "apps" page in your user profile contains the following phrase in the sidebar:

> The applications you have authorized with your Stack Exchange account are **list** here.

Should that be "listed"?

[image]

Comment: Your complaint are receive.

Comment: Good luck with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in a build later today, assuming we break from Diablo for more than a few minutes at any point.

Comment: Oh.. so **that's** where you have been! :D

Comment: Hmm.. since I got notification on this very answer it means [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54372/notify-me-of-updates-on-questions-i-put-a-bounty-on) is completed - right?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - yep, I'll mark it as such.

Comment: Cheers Nick please also mention when it was done so I can add to the changelog here on Meta. :)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - done...took a while to find since it was evidently 7 months ago (2010-10-07)

Comment: You mean **2011** right? (sorry for the hassle by the way..)

Comment: Err.. it still says "The applications you have authorized with your Stack Exchange account are list here" - anything happened to the scheduled fix? :(

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - Diablo 3 was released yesterday, what makes you think we ran a build? :)

Answer (score 2):

While changing that: maybe add a note about what "access to your information" actually means?

I would assume that things that are [private on your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97964/make-clear-which-profile-data-is-visible-to-whom) are invisible to authorized applications as well, but I am not sure. And what about downvotes? For example [SENotifier](https://stackapps.com/questions/3081/senotifier-a-stack-exchange-inbox-notifier-for-mac-os-x) mentions a "login token", but not what can be done with that.

(I am not using any apps. So if the above is clarified elsewhere, like during authorization, then please shout.)

Comment: Ah, Jumbo [referred](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133190/how-can-i-generate-unread-items-in-my-inbox-for-testing#comment369382_133190) me to [the documentation](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication#scope) and even [an example link](https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=326&scope=read_inbox,no_expiry&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success). (Save to click; you will still need to approve after clicking that link.)