# How can I generate unread items in my inbox for testing?

Tags: support, global-inbox

I am creating application that will notify me whenever I have unread messages in my SE inbox. **Is there some way to generate unread items for myself?** I am not such active user and I don't get new/unread messages often so it is hard to test this.

(Again, I am not sure if this do not belong to StackApps site, but I think this is SE feature question...)

Comment: This comment will generate a notification for you to test with.

Comment: This one will, too.

Comment: Make a sockpuppet and comment on your own posts.

Comment: Mary had a little lamb,

Comment: little lamb, ---

Comment: little lamb, ----

Comment: Mary had a little lamb,

Comment: Her fleece was white as snow.

Comment: lit-tle lamb. ---

Comment: @Pekka: So, if I need a notification to test one of my extensions, I can just bug you?

Comment: :D Thank you guys. My app seems to work for now :) I didn't know making a sockpuppet is legal, to be honest I didn't know the word sockpuppet :) I will create one, and use this post to spam myself :) Thanks again.

Comment: T̲̱hi͔̤̤ͅs̺̲͔̞̗ͅ ͕̟͙̭one͙ͅ ͇̫̰̟t̙͚o̙o͚̝͖̯̤̣͙.

Comment:    (one should really come prepared!)

Comment: @jumbo: Sock puppets should only get you in trouble in case of voting irregularities. Upvoting a post of one account using the other or voting twice on the same post can get you suspended. Pinging yourself should be fine.

Comment: thank you @Dennis. I will try to not get in trouble.

Comment: @jumbo _If_ you go with the sockpuppet, it'd be nice to include a link to the account in your main account's about box (and vice versa), and of course a sentence or two on why you need the sockpuppet. Also when you're done testing you're app, you should ask the mods (via a flag to one of your posts or through chat) to merge the accounts (which would invalidate any self voting). You know, just to be proper and all...

Comment: @Double AA Don't you want to make your comment into answer? I would accept it, as it solves my problem... ;)

Comment: @YannisRizos Thank to you too. I will do that. I want to have clean sockpuppet ;) (but if this comment-shower will last little longer, maybe I won't need any :D )

Comment: Just wondering, as you seem to know about the API: does *every* authorized application have access to all your data? ([The "apps" tab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131437/minor-spelling-mistake-on-the-authorized-applications-page) states "remove an app to remove access to your information"; just curious about that.)

Comment: 1 more to go...

Comment: @Arjan Are you asking me? Or are you trying to remind me of something?

Comment: I'm just asking. I couldn't find documentation about how authorizing an app works. (And I am not using any.) Like I saw that [SENotifier](http://stackapps.com/questions/3081/senotifier-a-stack-exchange-inbox-notifier-for-mac-os-x) mentions a login token. Just wondering if it's some "all or nothing" authorization. (But: totally off topic and not related to your question here! By the way: how's your app handling the ?)

Comment: @Arjan I think **Scope** parameter of authorization process is what are you asking about - here it is in [docs](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication#scope). For example [this is url](https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=326&scope=read_inbox,no_expiry&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success) requesting access to your inbox and no expiration.

Comment: @Arjan I am not dealing with Unicode in any way. I am reading only total count of new messages for my notifications ;)

Comment: There's even [notification notifications](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/) nowadays :-)

Comment: [I am a sockpuppet, may I exist if I have a real purpose?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65604/i-am-a-sockpuppet-may-i-exist-if-i-have-a-real-purpose)

Comment: @PopularDemand I already read this, but thanks anyway. The link should be mentioned here.

Comment: Yeah, I only commented to get that into the "Linked" section. I didn't say anything else because I didn't think you, specifically, needed to be told. Sorry if it came off that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend making a [sockpuppet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8/eggs-mclaren) and commenting on your own posts.

Disclaimer: Do not use the sockpuppet for voting or benefitting your account in any other way as this can get you in big trouble.