# Why did I not receive a notification for this answer to a bountied question?

Tags: bug, bounties, notifications

1. I placed a bounty on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291598/255554) by another user.
2. Two days later, the question received [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298911/255554) (which was deleted *after* the bounty expired).
3. I did not get a notification for this answer, [though I should](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132622/255554). (I thoroughly checked my notification history twice *before* the answer was deleted.)

Why did the system not work as expected? Note that I got the notifications that my bounty expires in X days.

Comment: I think you should get 2 or 3 notifications says the bounty will expire in x days (on the last 2) days on bounty period