# 'You have a new favorite change' is incorrect

Tags: support, answers, bookmarks

While browsing Programmers, I received a notification.

[image: screenshot]

The link took me to SE Programmer favorite list (since I was browsing programmers), but none of these questions have changed recently. This is my SE Programmer favorite tab:

[image: screenshot]

A question I asked earlier on SO Meta received a new answer within that time-frame, so I believe it was referring to that:

[image: screenshot]

The stuff that doesn't make sense:

- **(wrong site)** The "see your favorites" link goes to SE Programmer favorites when the item in question was on SO Meta
- **(wrong tab)** The link goes to my favorites tab when the item in question isn't on the favorites tab, it would be in the questions tab
- **(not favorite'd)** It says it is a favorite change, but I didn't favorite the question, I asked it. I saw the [discussion here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox), but I don't think the issue is addressed, as I didn't press the 'star' button on the SO Meta question I asked. I think [the reverse of this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3155/show-updates-to-favorite-questions-in-recent-activity/3808#3808) is happening.

Comment: Is this a brand new change within the last 24 hours? I have *never* seen a notification bar alerting me of a favorite change.

Comment: @Cody No, this is old.

Answer (score 3):

Have you browsed Programmers since Aug. 6 (the most recent change to one of the favorites)?  From your Activity tab, you haven't done anything between Aug. 3 and today.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't add one of your questions as favorite, then the notification is not referring to one of your questions. It is more probable it is referring to the question changed by Rasoul Zabihi on August 6.

Bear in mind that if one of the questions you added to your favorite is edited, or get a new answer, then you get a notification, which is not referring to the questions changed in the last 24 hours, but to the ones changed since the last time you visited that SE site.