# Getting e-mails for favorited questions

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

I know I am supposed to get e-mails everytime that someone replies to an answer I marked as favorite, but I just don't. Is there any setting I'm missing? Did I misunderstand something?
Thanks!

Comment: As usual: *what* have you tried? Did you [enable email notifications](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/improved-global-email-notifications/) at all? (That might not help, but we need to know what you tried.) And any reference for your *"I know I am supposed to get e-mails"*?

Comment: (As surely Inbox message can be sent by email, see also [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox).)

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to get *notified*, in the notification area, not emailed.

[image: notification area]

Comment: Well, that's also not working :/

Comment: What shows up in the `Favourites` tab of your profile?

Comment: At the bottom left of that same Stack Exchange box, there's [the email settings](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/improved-global-email-notifications/). Any idea if (the newer) notifications should be included in those too?

Comment: @Arjan - no idea. I wouldn't think so.

Comment: Okay, then I doubt there's some other setting, though [Jeff wrote in 2009](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3155/show-updates-to-favorite-questions-in-recent-activity/3808#3808) *"if you favorite a question, you opt in to updates on that question [...] just as if you own the question"* and despite that an OP *can* in fact get email notifications. (But, I know, that's a very old answer from Jeff.)

Comment: Indeed, @Miquel is correct: favorite changes are [not shown in the notifications](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jWj0g.png). So I guess they're still not shown anywhere, despite the team inquiring about [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox) in March 2011.

Comment: @Oded I just realized that, in my profile page, the favorites tab does light up and blue indicating new activity, that's great! However, as Arjan says, it still doesn't pop up in the notifications box. Another issue is that I wanted to *get an email* but it looks like that's just not possible

Comment: @oded Arjan's on to something check his link [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox)

Answer (score 1):

When a favorited question is updated (via a new comment or a new answer), the count on the dropdown at the top of the screen is updated.

[image]

So if anything new was added on that day, week, or month, respectively, the count is incremented.

It is shown on your profile as well, but this counts the number since you've selected that tab last:

[image]

I'm not aware of any other notifications on favorites, in the Collider or otherwise.

Comment: Ah, yes that does work and is very helpful, thanks! It does, however, not show anything on the StackExchange pull down (the one that @Oded screenshot)

Comment: @Miquel I've never seen a notification regarding one of my favorites in that area, so I'm not sure what should happen, but these two indicators do change.

Comment: thanks! It looks like I had the wrong expectations. Favorite notifications will never be sent by e-mail, and they will also [not pop up in the inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox)

Comment: @Miquel Yeah, I wish I had better news for you, but oh well.  I think your only hope is to put a bounty on that linked question.