# Order favorites by the date they were marked as favorite

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, bookmarks, sorting

Right now you can sort your favorites by *views*, *newest*, and *votes*.  (Someone also suggested being able to [sort by edit date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/995/possibility-to-order-favourites-by-most-recently-changed).)

Sometimes, chronological order helps my recall when searching for an item (default view for delicious).  Considering this, I suggest being able to sort favorites by the date they were marked as favorite (provided this information is tracked by SO.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now sort favorites by "latest" (CreationDate) or "recent" (LastActivityDate).

Note that by our definition, activity means only edits to question or answers, or new answers.

EDIT: new sort order for favorites, "added" (Date Favorited, which is a join to the votes table, so it is a little expensive)

Comment: Super cool Jeff!  Thanks so much.  That's is very useful.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! This means my request about "most recently changed" ordering (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/995/possibility-to-order-favourites-by-most-recently-changed) is implemented and could also be tagged 'completed' now.

Comment: (Although I fail to see how *this* particular FR, i.e., order by date of marking as favourite, is completed. Oh well, Traples seems to be happy, so maybe he didn't really need that after all. :-)

Comment: Something wrong: there is 'recent', 'views', **'newest'**, 'votes', no 'latest' (it was here). Neither gives me most recently added favorite.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15267/order-favorites-by-the-date-they-were-marked-as-favorite-does-not-work

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - But on the favorites list it seems to sort it {not sure} but does not show the date it was added to favorites - i.e. favorited. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

According to the edit Jeff gave - this is planned for implementation.  No timetable, but if you like it, vote up the question and the team will see a lot of people care about it.