# Order favorites by the date they were marked as favorite does not work

Tags: bug, status-completed, bookmarks, sorting

The feature request [Order favorites by the date they were marked as favorite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3369/order-favorites-by-the-date-they-were-marked-as-favorite) got implemented, and I used it to find questions most recently added to favorites.

But now there is something wrong with 'preferences' tab: you can sort preferences by 'recent', 'views', **'newest'**, 'votes': **there is no *'latest'*** (it was here).

'recent' has "sort by recent activity" tooltip (title), 'views' has "sort by most viewed", 'votes' has "sort by highest votes"... and 'newest' has "sort by newest", which explains *nothing*.  It looks like 'newest' sorts by the time question was asked, not when question was added as favorite.

This is a regression.

---

For example I remember that last question I marked as favorite was [Are Mutexes needed in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124764/are-mutexes-needed-in-javascript) (nb. I don't see anywhare information about when question was marked as favorite), and in my [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-narebski), when I choose ''newest' (there is no 'latest' as described in [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3369/order-favorites-by-the-date-they-were-marked-as-favorite) for this feature) this question is neither first, nor last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my comment, above -- there's a misunderstanding about how this works.

Since sorting by "date favorited" would require a fairly complex join to the votes table, this is unlikely to be implemented in the form you are requesting.

EDIT: I had a change of heart on this, so there is now an "added" sort on the favorites tab, which sorts by the date you added a question to your favorites.

Comment: But on the favorites list it seems to sort it {not sure} but does not show the date it was added to favorites - i.e. favorited. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

"Newest" does not sort by the time asked.  It looks to be the order favorited, at least according to my memory of my favoriting.

Comment: Can we really trust your memory?

Comment: Yay, you got an upside-down upvote!

Comment: Rock on.  I must be in now.